# как записать математическую формулу в строку в java?

Tags: java, строки

Хочу вывести строку в консоль вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите пожалуйста, какое значение в Java я должен присвоить строке, чтобы мне такую прелесть вывести в консоль?

Comment: Или в другой тип данных, который не является строкой. 
Как вариант: как создать объект, который выведет в консоль такую формулу?
Но желательно, всё-таки в строку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите сюда [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)

```
String test = "x³ + x² + 1 = y²";
System.out.println(test);
```

Output:

```
x³ + x² + 1 = y²
```

Comment: Это в какой кодировке у вас так лихо пошло?

Comment: У меня вывелось x? + x? + 1 = y?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin в терминале Ubuntu UTF-8

Comment: А у вас где это вывелось?

Comment: не поверите, в Intellij IDEA. 
UTF-8. Вот пруфпик http://vfl.ru/fotos/7deffdd910671640.html
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin, В IDEA тоже нормально выводит. Попробуйте в CMD, если вы на Windows.

Comment: Да вы, похоже, правы. Где то сбил настройки то ли IDE, то ли проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте все же используя [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)
  Вот как пример вашей функции

```
System.out.println("x\u00B2 + x\u00B3 + 1 = y\u00B2")
```

В итоге имеем

x² + x³ + 1 = y²

Comment: тоже тема, спасибо